# What is Euler's Formula when 2­-cell embedding condition was removed?

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

It is well known that **Euler's Formula** for genus $\gamma$: For every **2­-cell embedding** of a graph
on a surface with genus  $\gamma$, the numbers of vertices, edges, and faces satisfy
$n-e+f=2-2\gamma$.

**My quetion**: If the **2­-cell embedding** condition was removed,what will we  get?
Does following inequality hold true in general genus $\gamma$?
$$2-2\gamma\le n-e+f\le 2-2(\gamma-1)=2 \gamma$$
For example: We know a **toroidal graph** is a graph that can be embedded on a torus. So maybe  for embedding of any toroidal graph, we would get
$$0\le n-e+f\le 2. $$

If we consider following graph $C_6+e$, and the  toroidal embedding of $C_6+e$ contains $6$ vertices , $7$ edges and $2$ faces. so  $n-e+f=6-7+2=1$.
Obviously $0\le 1 \le 2$.
[image]

Comment: The lower bound is proven in "C. Thomassen, The Jordan-Schönflies Curve Theorem and the classification of surfaces, Amer. Math. Monthly 99 (1992) 116-130."

Comment: Thanks, I will read it.